# Read XHTML with XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, xhtml, parsing

How to read XHTML with XDocument, without downloading DTD. How to resolve the DTD references? No, you can't just say:

```
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
settings.XmlResolver = null;
```

as given in some previous answer, which is absolutely wrong. What about the entities then: `&nbsp;` 
Also I am not interested in HTMLAgility pack, again wrong answer, as I have valid XHTML.

Comment: Can you explain why not to use HAP?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913214/system-xml-xmldocument-whats-the-best-way-to-cache-an-external-dependency-dtd

Comment: HAP has lots of issues, highly unstable, also this is absolutely not needed for this situation, using XmlResolver it a better choice, but I am still looking for even better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, you have to manually cache all the DTD (see Mauricio Scheffer comment above), it looks like the best solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669135.aspx

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid94A10BEBC204E95FF8C314E657E2E4DA86B5BEFD.aspx?s=httpwebrequest#L50

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/HTML2XHTML.aspx